# WinError 2 with Anaconda installed "The system cannot find the file specified" on any Python code through Sublime Text 4

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext

Recently installed Anaconda as I wish to delve more into data science and machine learning, and am trying to set up my Sublime Text to be my main editor, which it did used to be when I had just Python installed.

I uninstalled everything python related, and installed just Anaconda, changing the PATH from the normal python path to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts and C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3. I reinstalled ST3, where the code did work, and then updated to ST4. (*this is an edit, I had not realised my ST3 had updated to 4 when I first posted.*)

I made sure that the command `python` works in cmd, and though I do get a warning;

**""Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see [https://conda.io/activation""](https://conda.io/activation%22%22)**

a `print("Hello World")` statement works.

Moving on to Sublime Text, I attempted to test the same command and am met with an error;

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['py', '-u', '']]
[dir: E:\Programs\Sublime Text 3]
[path: C:\Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\Users\seabr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\MinGW-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\;C:\Users\seabr\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;]
[Finished]
```

I attempted to fix this by checking the sublime-build file for Python using PackageResouceViewer and changing python3 to python in there, which did not fix the issue. I then installed the conda package which when ran does not give me a build output, but looking into the sublime text console I can see;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1104, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programs\Sublime Text 3\Lib\python33\sublime_plugin.py", line 1456, in run_
    return self.run(**args)
  File "C:\Users\seabr\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Installed Packages\Conda.sublime-package\commands.py", line 682, in run
  File "C:\Users\seabr\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Installed Packages\Conda.sublime-package\commands.py", line 645, in __enter__
  File "C:\Users\seabr\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Installed Packages\Conda.sublime-package\commands.py", line 629, in conda_version
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 576, in check_output
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 819, in __init__
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1110, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

[This](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/winerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/15372) is the closest I can find to my situation, but following the fixes in there also have not fixed my issue.

In essense, I'm not sure whether this is an issue with my anaconda environment, my sublime text or my windows PATH, so any help would be greatly appricated and I'm happy to provide more information if it is needed

Comment: You haven't saved your file before running it. Running a build uses the last saved file version, but you haven't saved it yet.

Comment: I was trying to fix this today, I reinstalled ST3 (not 4) and caught myself not saving it, however on realising this I saved and it worked. I decided to test ST4 and updated (which as I found out my old install of ST3 had already done) and even with the file saved I get the above errors, I'll update my post accordingly but the issue unfortunaley remains.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating to `Sublime Text 4`.
I fixed it by changing **`python3`** to **`python`** (like you mentioned trying) and also **`py`** to **`python`** in my `Python.sublime-build`.
Hope this works.

Comment: can you tell me how you set it up? step by step?